# Integral with Bessel function and sine.

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions

How to evaluate the integral with Bessel function:

$\int_0^{2\pi}J_1(x\sin\theta)\sin^2\theta d\theta$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is $0$. $ $ $ $

Comment: Use the series form of $J_1$ and change the sum and integral, then prove $$\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^{2k+3}t\ dt=0$$